# CSS background image not showing up in my deployed site

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my background image to show up on the top of the screen to cover the whole game with the text and the username input box and button on top of the image. But for some reason, my image is not showing up.

When I try to host the website through the Live Server extension, it seems to be working

Background image is appearing from Live Server extension:

[image: background image is appearing from Live Server extension]

But when I deployed it via GitHub pages, it doesn't seem to work

Background image not showing up on GitHub Pages:

[image: background image not showing up on GitHub Pages]

```css
.start-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    background-image: url(/assets/images/start-window-image.webp);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="start-container">
        <div class="start-title">
            <h1>FOODle</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="start-body">
            <h3>Enter a username:</h3>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required>
                <button id="start-button">Start</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Also here's my [github repo](https://github.com/yamesjamess/p2-project-foodle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your **background-image** url to:

```
background-image: url("../images/start-window-image.webp");
```

Because from the CSS file you are going one directory up, then going to images, then to your desired image.